# What's more profitable for me? To put my ideas on a blog or youtube?

Tags: youtube, blogs, adsense

Blog vs youtube revenues? This is the question.
I have some solutions to IT problems that i know they are unique and unsolved, as i searched all over the place and didn't find answers.
Now i want to share this and i wonder how it would be the best way to do this considering revenues? I guess i can resume it to adsense vs youtube?
I have no ideea which is more profitable, or if there is any other way which i didn't think of and would be more profitable than those two.
Please consider i do not have too much time to invest in for ex finding contracts to advertise independently on my blog let's say. I want to write it (blog), or post it (youtube) and forget about it, or do minimal maintenance (1h/week).

Thank you in advance people :)

Comment: I don't think you should post this question on stackoverflow ...

Answer (score 0):

Put your ideas on your youtube with a link onscreen and on the description to your blog. This way your ideas will have more visibility.